# Escaping a period in tag name using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an XML file to parse. Here are some example data:

```
<result>
            <name>chemical name</name>
            <description></description>
            <ec---list-no.>1123-34-6</ec---list-no.>
            <cas-no.>321-98-7</cas-no.>
            <decision-type>Important</decision-type>
            <decision>http://link to decision</decision>
            <decision-date>12/06/2011</decision-date>
            <further-information></further-information>
            <remarks></remarks>
            <dossier-url>http://link</dossier-url>
</result>
```

If I want to extract the names, for example, this works:

```
doc.xpath('//result').each do |record|
  name = record.at('name').text
  puts name
end
```

However, I cannot extract the `ec--list-no` or `cas-no` data, because the tag names contain a period `"."`.

```
doc.xpath('//result').each do |record|
  cas = record.at('cas-no.').text
  puts cas
end
```

throws an error.

```
unexpected '$' after '.'
```

I tried to escape it with a backslash `"\"`, but to no avail. Also various combinations of single and double quotes. My search for CSS escape characters has so far been fruitless.

Is there and elegant way to escape the period, or do I need to go back to the drawing board?

Answer (score 0):

This works for my. Does this help?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

s = "<result>
  <name>chemical name</name>
  <description></description>
  <ec---list-no.>1123-34-6</ec---list-no.>
  <cas-no.>321-98-7</cas-no.>
  <decision-type>Important</decision-type>
  <decision>http://link to decision</decision>
  <decision-date>12/06/2011</decision-date>
  <further-information></further-information>
  <remarks></remarks>
  <dossier-url>http://link</dossier-url>
</result>"

doc = Nokogiri::XML( s )
doc.xpath( "//result" ).each do | record |
  pp name = record.xpath( "cas-no." )
end
```

Comment: Thank you - yes this works, and without the need for pp.